# Обновление блока js

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой код который обновляет `div` с `id="com_project"`

```
$("#com_project").load("blocks/com_project.php");
```

Суть в том что он выполняется только у того кто вызвал данную функцию.
Как можно обновить данный div блок у всех кто находится на данной странице?
Есть обновление каждые 5 секунд но это не совсем подходит.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
   $("#com_project").load("blocks/com_project.php");
 }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Кто такие «у того», кто такие «у всех»? Непонятно ничего

Comment: @andreymal смотрите 2 компьютера, на одной странице.

Comment: @andreymal вот как через ajax выполнить код на всех компьютерах, которые находятся на данной странице?

Comment: «Есть обновление каждые 5 секунд но это не совсем подходит» — почему не подходит-то? Судя по остальному тексту вопроса, это как раз отлично подходит

Comment: @andreymal в div блоке находятся изображения и на мобильных устройствах заметно как они мигают каждые 5 секунд. + нагрузка на сервер.

Comment: Нагрузка на сервер неизбежно будет, раз вы хотите блок обновлять. Отправляйте ajax-запрос и датой последнего обновления блока и читайте ответ, если сервер не пришлёт ничего — значит обновлений нет и ничего не делаем, если пришлёт html-код с обновлениями — то обновляем (и дату последнего обновления запоминаем). Ну или вебсокет, но вы видимо не осилите